# Small sum-of-squares coincidence

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory

I'm doing a reading course right now in the complex representation theory of finite groups, one of the fundamental results of which is the fact that a group with $n$ conjugacy classes has $n$ representations, which have degrees dividing the order of the group and whose squares sum to the order of the group.

When dealing with small examples, this information is often enough uniquely to pin down the character degrees (given the conjugacy-class count).  My question is:  what is a small example of integers $N$ and $n$ for which there are two distinct ways of writing $N = \sum_{i = 1}^n d_i^2$, where each $d_i$ is a positive integer dividing $N$?

Despite the motivation, I don't expect the answer to have any particular representation-theoretic significance, but, if it does, then, in addition to my upvote, I'll think good thoughts about you.  In particular, it would be great if $n$ were actually the count of the number of conjugacy classes in some group of order $N$, and the sequences of $d$'s were actually the degree sequences of some group of order $N$ with $n$ conjugacy classes.

Comment: Sums of eight squares has a quasi-charming modular-forms explication, for example, though without the direct repn-of-finite-groups interpretation. Or, dihedral groups? The irreducibles are all small (one or two-dimensional), but/and there are many other groups of orders $2n$...

Comment: @paulgarrett, thanks for the 8-squares suggestion, the details of which I'm afraid I don't know.  (Do you have an easy pointer?)  if I understand your second suggestion correctly, then I'm not sure looking at particular groups will help me; I don't know how to produce pairs of groups with the same orders and numbers of conjugacy classes, but different representation degrees.

Comment: The sum-of-eight-squares thing is a classic, though I do not know an original source. I worked it out for some course notes, in section 5 of http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_2013-14/10_thetas_equi.pdf  About the literal finite-groups thing, I don't really know much, just that dihedral groups are not completely trivial, yet easily understood...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one class of examples (for the first part of your question) . . .

Let $n$ be any multiple of $6$ with $n \ge 12$, and let $N=n+24$.

Define sequences $(a_k)$, $(b_k)$, by

$$a_k=
\begin{cases}
2&\text{if}\;1 \le k \le 8\\[2pt]
1&\text{if}\;9 \le k \le n\\[2pt]
\end{cases}
$$

$$b_k=
\begin{cases}
3&\text{if}\;1 \le k \le 3\\[2pt]
1&\text{if}\;4 \le k \le n\\[2pt]
\end{cases}
$$

Then

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k^2 = (n-8)(1^2) + 8(2^2) =  n + 24 = N$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k^2 = (n-3)(1^2) + 3(3^2) =  n + 24 = N$$

and all terms of both sequences divide $N$ (since $6\mid n$).

Comment: Did you generate this by brute force, or was there some guiding principle?  Do you know if it is the smallest such example?

Comment: And, to continue peppering you with questions, do you happen to know if there is a group of order $60$ with $36$ conjugacy classes?

Comment: For the brute force question, not exactly. I was sure it was possible, so I just set up some diophantine equations using values 1,2,3 and unknown multiplicities. I can probably find a smaller example.

Comment: For the group question, I have no idea.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I'll wait a while before accepting to see if anyone can satisfy that extra requirement.

Comment: In any case, even if there is a group of order $60$ with $36$ conjugacy classes, it certainly can't have $28$ or $33$ representations of degree $1$—which makes me realise that I meant to see if it were possible to get one or both of the $d$ sequences to be an actual degree sequence.  I'll edit that into the original question, too.